# dynamically asigning instances in Python/PyQt4

Tags: python, dynamic, pyqt4, instances, getattr

Ok, this might be a duplicate, but as I couldn't really get anything out of (possibly) similar questions, here is mine: I'm working on a small PyQt4 program where I can enter the name of a song in a QLineEdit and then add a QLabel of it beneath it. I want a button beside each one of these labels that deletes the label when clicked. Relevant code:

```
    def Add(self):


        self.rf= QtGui.QLabel(self.le1.text(),self)
        self.rf.move(45,30)
        self.rf.resize(450,30)
        self.rf.show()


        self.x = QtGui.QPushButton("X",self)
        self.x.move(10,30)
        self.x.resize(30,30)
        self.x.show()
        self.x.clicked.connect(self.Del)


    def Del(self):

        self.rf.close()
        self.x.close()
```

Now, what I'm not understanding is how I can assign a different instance to each of these dynamically added Qlabels, in order to delete the specific one when the button is clicked.

The best idea I had was creating a variable containing a number that would change with each added QLabel, something like var = rf+str(num) and num = 0, then adding 1 to num for each QLabel and then using getattr for the instances, so getattr(self, var) = Qtgui.QLabel(...), which unfortunately gives me an error that I can't assign that value to the function. And I can't create a dictionary since I have to have different instances for that.

Any ideas would be highly appreciated, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep them all in a dict and then key that off of the label text. It also provides a quick way to check for duplicates.